# How to suppress express:router logs?

Tags: express

An application I'm taking over is dumping a ton of useless express logs into the console. Is there any way to suppress express:router logs or determine where theyre coming from? It doesnt appear to be using morgan, and i cant find a specific logging middleware. I've included at least the app.js

a small fraction of the useless express:router logs:

> express:router:layer new '/api/profile-pic' +0ms
> express:router:route get '/api/profile-pic' +0ms
> express:router:layer new '/' +0ms   express:router:route get
> '/api/profile-pic' +0ms   express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
> express:router:route new '/api/upload-picture' +0ms
> express:router:layer new '/api/upload-picture' +0ms
> express:router:route post '/api/upload-picture' +0ms
> express:router:layer new '/' +0ms   express:router:route post
> '/api/upload-picture' +0ms   express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
> express:router:route post '/api/upload-picture' +0ms
> express:router:layer new '/' +0ms   express:router:route new
> '/apple-app-site-association' +0ms   express:router:layer new
> '/apple-app-site-association' +0ms   express:router:route get
> '/apple-app-site-association' +0ms   express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
> express:application set "x-powered-by" to true +1ms
> express:application set "etag" to 'weak' +0ms   express:application
> set "etag fn" to [Function: generateETag] +0ms   express:application
> set "env" to 'development' +1ms   express:application set "query
> parser" to 'extended' +0ms

app.js

```
require('dotenv').config({
  path: `./env-files/${process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'}.env`,
});
admin = require("firebase-admin");
const streamifier = require("streamifier")

var globalPath = require('path');
global.appRoot = globalPath.resolve(__dirname);

var serviceAccount = require("./env-files/[redacted].json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "[redacted]"
});

Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

storage = new Storage({
  projectId: '[redacted]',
  keyFilename: '[redacted]',
});


//admin.firestore.setLogFunction(console.log);

db = admin.firestore();





const multer = require('multer');
var storagetype = multer.memoryStorage();
m = multer({
  storage: storagetype,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024 // no larger than 5mb
  }
 });
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');




const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');


const staticFolder = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'public' : 'public';
const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(expressLayouts);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, staticFolder)));


// // Middleware used for setting error and success messages as available in _ejs_ templates
// app.use((req, res, next) => {
//   if (req.session) {
//     res.locals.messages = req.session.messages;
//     res.locals.userInfo = req.session.userInfo;
//     req.session.messages = {};
//   }
//   next();
// });

app.use('/', indexRouter);


// catch errors and prevent render them
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error('Uncaught Errors:', err);
  res.status(500);
  res.send('Error: Something went wrong');
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404).render('pages/404');
});

process.on('uncaughtException', uncaughtException => {
  console.error('Uncaught Exception:', uncaughtException);
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', reason => {
  console.error('Unhandled Rejection at:', reason);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project must have some Debug flags turned on.  You will need to find where they are specified and remove them.  You can read [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html) about how you control debug options in Express.

For example, if you set this in your environment:

```
DEBUG=express:*
```

Then, express will enable all its debug tracing.  So, since I don't see that in any of the code you posted, it must be either in the console/system environment or in the `.env` file in your project (since the project is using the `dotenv` module to load environment variables).

Comment: ...and just like that, i can feel my headache receding. thank you